# Make url using this two form actions

Tags: php

I want to make an URL like

```
localhost:81/en/ads/maincategory?sub=something&sort=something
```

using two forms(actions). But the first form should be sort.

How can I do this using PHP or HTML? (or any other method)

Thank You!

Comment: you can simply store the data for sort and sub in array and create a url at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `form` attribute

```html
<form id="main-form" method="get" target="localhost:81/en/ads/maincategory">
    <h3>In real Form:</h3>
    sorting: <input name="sort" value="something"><br>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
<section id="fake-form">
    <h3>In Fake-Form:</h3>
    sub: <input name="sub" form="main-form" value="something"><br>
    <button form="main-form">submit</button>
</section>
```

Read more on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form